# How to Exclude Class in Parent Xpath Class? PHP

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

Driving me up the wall, it's like this, the DOM

```
<div class="product-intro"><p class="product-desc"><span class="product-model">234</span>Product Description</p></div>
```

It's not anything like this... invalid argument, no nodes found:

```
$node3 = $xp->query("//p[@class='product-desc and not(@class='product-model']");
$node3 = $xp->query("//p[@class='product-desc'][not([@class='product-model'])]");
```

This alone:

```
$node3 = $xp->query("//p[@class='product-desc']");
```

Works perfectly well and fine-- as far as getting a result.
The output is

> 234Product Description

I know I could just do a string replace, but not ideally.. How do I get it to exclude the `product-model` class in my query?

Entire script:

```
$x = '<div class="product-item productContainer" data-itemno="234">
    <div class="product-and-intro">
        <div class="product">
            <a href="/en/234.html" title="Product Description"> 
                <img src="/ProductImages/106/234.jpg" alt="Product Description" class="itemImage" />
                <div class="product-intro">
                    <p class="product-desc"><span class="product-model">234</span>Product Description</p>
                    <p class="price"><span class="us">US$</span>6.50 <span class="oldprice"><s>$ 13.00</s></span></p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';



$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($x);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$node1 = $xp->query("//div[@class='product']//img");
$node2 = $xp->query("//span[@class='product-model']");
$node3 = $xp->query("//p[@class='product-desc']");
// $node3 = $xp->query("//p[@class='product-desc']/text()[2]");
// $node3 = $xp->query("//p[@class='product-desc' and not(span/@class='product-model')]");
$node4 = $xp->query("//p[@class='price']");

foreach ($node1 as $n) {
    echo $n->getAttribute('src');
    echo '<br>';
}

foreach ($node2 as $n2) {
    echo $n2->nodeValue;
        echo '<br>';
}

foreach ($node3 as $n3) {
    echo $n3->nodeValue;
        echo '<br>';
}

foreach ($node4 as $n4) {
    echo $n4->nodeValue;
        echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select all `p` elements with a `@class` attribute value of `product-desc` and then filter out those who have a `span` sub-element with the `@class` attribute value `product-model` you can use this XPath expression:

```
//p[@class='product-desc' and not(span/@class='product-model')]
```

Or, in a whole

```
$node3 = $xp->query("//p[@class='product-desc' and not(span/@class='product-model')]");
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that like to I thought.  Copied and pasted your exact whole code, and did the first one.. not working, no results

Comment: Yes. No results is the correct result. This expression doesn't select the `p` element because the predicate evaluates to `FALSE`. That's the way XPath works.

Comment: If you want, for example, get the `Product Description` string, use `//p[@class='product-desc']/text()[2]` as the XPath expression.

Comment: So there is no way to return just the product-desc class without also bringing in the product-model class?

Comment: Looked like it would of worked.. still not.... here i'll edit my main post with my full code, maybe that will help.

Comment: I, unfortunately, expected that question, because the answer is NO. XPath *does merely select* nodes. So the content is a completely different aspect. You can select a node - which includes all subnodes - but you haven't to get all of its content.

Comment: Oh hey, I got it! Just doing `/text()` worked.. adding [1] or [2] broke the query for whatever reason.  And your recent comment.. thank you! That is good to know.  And thanks overall it was a challenge lol. Have a good one!

Comment: Actually thinking about it.. I wonder why just doing /text() didn't bring them both in if what you said was accurate (which I'm sure it is).. maybe I still don't get it fully still, will have to read up on it more or something.  Have to head out for now thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could be of some help. Concerning your last question: each _non-empty_ `text()` counts as a node. So the index may vary if a now empty text-node turns to be non-empty.